# checks-Effects-interactions and the invariants

Tags: reentrant-attacks, vulnerability

Kindly check the following link for the paper (section 2.1.5):

[SmartCheck paper](https://s-tikhomirov.github.io/assets/papers/smartcheck.pdf)
From the paper:

```
Use the “checks – effects – interactions“
pattern: (a)first check the invariants, (b)then update the internal state,
(c)then communicate with external entities (see also Section 2.1.4):

1.function withdraw () public {
2.uint balance = balances [ msg . sender ];
3.balances [ msg . sender ] = 0;
4.msg . sender . transfer ( balance );
// state reverted , balance restored if transfer fails
}
```

Which is the invariant in the above code? If balances[msg.sender] is the invariant, then its value changes in line#3.
Somebody, please guide me with step (a) of the checks-effects-interactions pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this slightly modified example might be more generic as the CHECK step is clearly present (I believe they omitted it as someone withdrawing 0 is not a problem for the system… just wasted gas for the caller).

```
function withdraw () public {
    // CHECK
    require(balances[msg.sender] > 0);
    // EFFECT
    uint256 balance = balances[msg.sender];
    balances[msg.sender] = 0;
    // INTERACTION
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(balance);
    // state reverted , balance restored if transfer fails
}
```

It's just simpler to understand the invariant as the conditions required to move forward in the code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is that if you are considering balances array as invariant then why its value is changing?

Comment: No the balances mapping is not an invariant. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/112088/5032971. This is why I explained that the invariant is more about the conditions that allow you to move forward. Your example doesn't show any invariant ( hence your interogations ). So don't consider balances as an invariant because it is not.

Comment: Thanks. I understood. You mean that for successful execution of withdraw(), your condition in line#3 should always be true.